# Configurable Product - Get image ID from simple product

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-images, gallery

I have a problem regarding the productimages/image gallery in a product that is configurable.

**Question**

Is there a way to get a ID of the Simple Products Image and link it to open the right image in the gallery?

**User case**

When one click a certain color variation the respective simple product image is shown, eg. from orange to purple.

If one then click/trigger the gallery by pressing the "purple"  product image, the gallery list - `.more-views` -  does not show the purple, but the original "first image orange" in the gallery.

**Data dumping**

I have logged the `$_product->getData()` to see if there is any way to dig out a "Image ID" of the associated product without any luck.

[image]